# HTML table with Top and left Headers using php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this in the database:

```
(`id`,`cid`,`subheading`,`name`,`percentage`) 

VALUES

(1, 43, 'Big Bang / Evolution Theory',  'Jackie',   '9.7'),
(2, 43, 'Big Bang / Evolution Theory',  'Beth', '2.0'),
(3, 43, 'Creation / Creation Theory',   'Jackie',   '1.5'),
(4, 43, 'Creation / Creation Theory',   'Beth', '8.2'),
```

I want to display a html table using php mysql to output names along the left side which could grow to 100 or more and along the top would be the subheadings which could grow to more than 2 but at this stage its 2.

The cid is the unique identifier as there would be more table groups but this one is all related to cid = 43.

I have provided a screen grab of how i want it.

[image]

Here are some of the things that confuse me.

With all the queries i have tried no matter how many variations I can not seem to understand the logic of looping this through.

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <?php SELECT subheading FROM ... WHERE cid=43 GROUP BY subheading
        foreach (headings as subheading) { ?>
        <th scope="col">echo subheading/th>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <?php SELECT name FROM ... WHERE cid=43
        foreach (names as name) { ?>
        <th scope="row">echo name</th>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php SELECT percentage FROM ... WHERE cid=43
        foreach (percentages as percentage) { ?>
        <td>echo percentage</td>
        <?php } ?>      
    </tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there some way of creating one query to manage this all? I am not allowed to change th structure of the table data though.

Comment: This is not a good way to do it at all. First select everything you need, make variables (arrays) with the texts, and then print it with for loop (row by row)

Comment: @MightyPork thanks fro your feedback, could you please help me with that? i am only learning and i understand for each loops but not how to use arrays within a scenario like this. I have tried so many different arrays and still keep getting stuck with strange limitations to the data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that much time. It looks like you don't even know how to query a database. I'd suggest you first get something basic working and ask again. Try to use mysqli.

Comment: No worries mate! then don't comment. I put the MySQL in as short hand because i figured people like you would get the picture. If you don't have time then don't answer at all please.

Comment: I would help fix the code, but as it is, I'd have to reinvent your queries etc. Your "simplification" actually made it harder to answer.

Comment: Ok no probs, ill work at it. I tried simplifying it in order to see if anyone can help with the logic of the queries. As i said i have tried lots of variations including arrays and looping the <tr> etc.. but can not seem to get it. If i posted all the things i tried it would have looked messy. I'm simply after the logic. How do you loop subheadings and then rows to echo the data without being limited by any one loop.

Comment: As I said you query everything at the top, and then just print it. Embedding MYSQL queries in your HTML is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I would change the table structure but as you said you cannot do that.  Will each name have a value for each subheading?  I'm going to assume yes as that simplifies things.  In that case I would simply order everything alphabetically.

We'll need one query to get the headings in alphabetical order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subheading FROM ... WHERE cid=43 ORDER BY subheading
```

Retrieve those and loop through them to print the headings.

Next you'll need a second query to retrieve the display data:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE cid=43 ORDER BY name, subheading
```

Then you can loop through those results and build the table.  The results will be ordered by name first so with some simple variable checks you can determine when the name changes (meaning you need to start the next row).  Within a single name the results are then ordered by the subheadings in alphabetical order so you can simply display the percentages in order (again, this assumes that a name has data for each subheading).

If you need to do this for all the cid values, you could wrap the entire thing in a for loop that runs through the cid values.

Comment: Yes wow, thanks for this! I am going to read through again a few times and make an attempt to apply your advice. It makes sense. Thank you so much. I'll come back later and give you the tick etc... :)